# Crash when class write to console

Tags: c#, class, console

I'm going to get another user and enter which month he wants and find the quarter.

Thought of writing the code inside a class as I need more training on how to use classes.

The program asks whose month it is and I can enter. But now when I type "January" only programs crash.

I assume that it should show which quarter "january" is in

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write a month");
        
        var mc = new MyClass();
        mc.month = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string month;

        public string Prop
        {
            get
            {
                return month;
            }
            set
                { if (Prop == "january")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("1.quarter");
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your property setter should not be responsible for anything except setting that property's value. It should not be writing a program result to the console. Also, `Convert.ToString()` is not necessary because `Console.ReadLine()` already returns a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider presenting a menu which in the case below uses a NuGet package [Spectre.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spectre.Console/0.44.1-preview.0.34) and [docs](https://spectreconsole.net/). This gives you an opportunity to work with classes and ensures, in this case input is a valid month along with reties and how to exit.

[image]

First a class for the menu.

```
public class MonthItem
{
    public int Index { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public MonthItem(int index, string name)
    {
        Index = index;
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

Class which creates the menu

```
class MenuOperations
{

    public static SelectionPrompt<MonthItem> SelectionPrompt()
    {
        var menuItemList = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select((index) =>
            new MonthItem(index, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(index)))
            .ToList();

        menuItemList.Add(new MonthItem(-1, "Exit"));

        SelectionPrompt<MonthItem> menu = new()
        {
            HighlightStyle = new Style(Color.Black, Color.White, Decoration.None)
        };

        menu.Title("[yellow]Select a month[/]");
        menu.PageSize = 14;
        menu.AddChoices(menuItemList);

        return menu;

    }
}
```

Present menu, get selection and show details or exit.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Clear();

        var menuItem = AnsiConsole.Prompt(MenuOperations.SelectionPrompt());
        if (menuItem.Index != -1)
        {
            AnsiConsole.MarkupLine($"[b]{menuItem.Name}[/] index is [b]{menuItem.Index}[/]");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and your program is not crashing. The program is actually completing and therefore the console is closing due to execution completing. So you can see what I mean try changing your code to this. You will see your code loop and the console will not close. It will also display what the user types in for `mc.month`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write a month");

        var mc = new MyClass();
        mc.month = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(mc.month);
    }
}
```

On a side note, not really how I would use a class. You might want to also rethink that. Don't normally see writelines in class.

Comment: then the consoll is writing "jauary and " write a month" so didnt work

Comment: This wasn't designed to fix other things. It was to show you why your console was closing, which is what your original question asked.